# How to use Bootstrap with WP's jQuery?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using WP's local jQuery. All my own scripts are working fine! But bootstrap gives me this error message in the console: `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery`.

How can I make bootstrap using WP's local jQuery?

Comment: Share your code please, how you enqueued your javascripts etc. And using bootstrap's jQuery is not different in WordPress. You are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, using WP methods to [enqueue](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) bootstrap JS dependencies you can just set jQuery as a requirement and WordPress will take care of the rest.

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js', array( 'jquery' ) ); ?>
```